# Two way binding using value set by AJAX - Observable doesn't notify when setting control's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

So, I have a simple page below where the rate field is set by AJAX. However the other calculated fields do not seem to get updated in the view model by KnockoutJS unless I type in the actual value for rate. How can this be resolved?

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    Date: <input type="text" data-bind="value: date" id="txtDate" /><br />
    Enter Amount: <input type="text" data-bind="value: amount" /><br />
    Rate: <input type="text" data-bind="value: rate" id="txtRate" /><br />
    VAT: <input type="text" data-bind="value: vat" /><br />
    Total Amount: <input type="text" data-bind="value: totalAmount" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#txtDate').change(function(){
            $.getJSON('/api/Common/GetRate', { param: $(this).val() }).success(function (data) {
                $('#txtRate').val(data);
            });
        });
    });

    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.date = ko.observable('');
        self.amount = ko.observable(0);
        self.rate = ko.observable(0);
        self.vat = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            return self.amount() * 0.1;
        }, this);
        self.totalAmount = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            return self.amount() + self.vat();
        }, this);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

</script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to change `self.amount() * 0.1` to `self.amount() * self.rate()` if you expect `self.vat` to be updated on `self.rate` change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up jQuery and Knockout, which is always a bad idea.

On the ajax call success, update the observable value, which is the KO way. To do so you need to create the view model before doing the ajax call, and store it in a variable, for example:

```
var vm = AppViewModel();
```

Then, on the AJAX call success callback, update the observable value, i.e.:

```
vm.rate(data);
```

You should always do it in this way: update the bound value, and the control will reflect the changes. As you've seen trying to do it the other way round is problematic, apart from more difficult.

It doesn't matter if you apply the binding before of after the callback.

And a final note: when you define computed observable the second parameter is to bind the callback function to it. I.e. it will be the value of `this` inside the function. So, it would make sense to do this:

```
 self.vat = ko.pureComputed(function () {
      return this.amount() * 0.1;
 }, self);
```

but what you're doing is pointless. You can omit that second parameter if you don't use `this` inside the computed function.

*NOTE: apart from being a bad idea, the reason why updating the value using jQuery doesn't work is because knockout bindings use events to be able to update observables. When you use jQuery to set the value, no events are triggered, so the observable isn't updated. Please, see the docs for [value binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html), and pay special attention to `valueUpdate` parameter description.*

Comment: Thanks for your views and code. I tried setting the rate to use json returned value but the model does not update. Below is code: `rate: ko.computed(function(){
 $.getJSON('/api/Common/GetRate', { param: self.date() }).success(function (data) {
                return data
            });
})`

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but your `getJSON` runs whenever `date()` changes, and then you get the responde from the service and return it "to noone". I.e. you return the value without taking it or using it for anything. Perhaps you meant `vm.rate(data)` instead of `return data`

Comment: I want to return the value to "rate" property of the view model. So `self.rate = get rate using ajax call`

Comment: The is what I've told you in my previous comment. Rememebr that to change a ko observable you must do `vm.rate(data)` and not `vm.rate = data`. If it isn't working, open your console and debug. the code is correct.

Comment: Actually I am trying to change that and set the rate in a `ko.computed` function in the view model.